# How to set focus on a edit box in matlab using guide

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide

I am using MatLab to create an application using guide to design my figures. My question is how do I set focus on a edit box when the figure loads? The reason why I am using Matlab is because it the only development system I have to use.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out, you have to put uicontrol(txtFirstName) in the output function when using guide generated gui.

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with uicontrol in this case is that the figure has to be 'Visible' before you can set focus on any of the sub-figures.

I never found a good way to do this in Guide (or better, in the guide-generated m-file), but one thing that usually works is to put on the last lines of YourFig_OpeningFcn:

```
set(handles.mainFigure, 'Visible', 'on');
uicontrol(handles.txtFirstName,'String','');
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know that object's handle, say `h`. If you don't know it (for example because you use Guide), set the `'tag'` property of that object with a unique string, and then the handle can be found with [`findobj`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/findobj.html):

```
h = findobj('tag','example tag string');
```

Once you know the handle of the edit object, to set focus on it simply use [`uicontrol`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/uicontrol.html) as follows:

```
uicontrol(h)
```

More information [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98603-how-do-i-force-my-gui-to-give-focus-to-a-specific-uicontrol).

Comment: I tried that but it did not work. I used this code on a button and it did set focus. uicontrol(handles.txtFirstName,'String',''); How can I set focus or put the cursor on txtFirstName when the figure loads?

Comment: Try putting that code in the figure's `'CreateFcn'` property

Comment: Tried it but no joy :( You would figure Matlab would have made it easy to do a simple task of setting focus to a control on figure load.